Appium Inspector: Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unable to start WebDriverAgent session
Afternoon All,
I'm struggling trying to start a session from the latest version of the Appium inspector app after starting a new Appium server session from the Terminal.
I can get the iOS simulator to boot but run into problems when trying to bring up the app.
I get the following error in the command-line (and a subsequent error in the inspector complaining about capabilities I haven't even set in the inspector - and unfortunately can't be over-ridden in the inspector either)
Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unable to start WebDriverAgent session. Original error: All non-standard capabilities should have a vendor prefix.
Appium Version: 2.11.3
Xcode: 12.4 (latest available to Mac OS Catalina)
Mac: Catalina (10.5.7)
iPhone: 14.4 (simulator)
Appium Inspector version: 2024.6.1
Desired Capabilities Set In Appium Inspector:
{
  "appium:app": "/Users/dangood/Desktop/UIKitCatalog.app",
  "appium:automationName": "XCUITest",
  "appium:deviceName": "iPhone 12 Pro",
  "appium:platformName": "iOS",
  "appium:platformVersion": "14.4",
  "appium:wdaLocalPort": "4723"
}

Server Output:
[HTTP] --> POST /session {"capabilities":{"alwaysMatch":{"appium:app":"/Users/dangood/Desktop/UIKitCatalog.app","appium:automationName":"XCUITest","appium:deviceName":"iPhone 12 Pro","appium:platformName":"iOS","appium:platformVersion":"14.4","appium:wdaLocalPort":"4723","appium:newCommandTimeout":3600,"appium:connectHardwareKeyboard":true},"firstMatch":[{}]},"desiredCapabilities":{"appium:app":"/Users/dangood/Desktop/UIKitCatalog.app","appium:automationName":"XCUITest","appium:deviceName":"iPhone 12 Pro","appium:platformName":"iOS","appium:platformVersion":"14.4","appium:wdaLocalPort":"4723","appium:newCommandTimeout":3600,"appium:connectHardwareKeyboard":true}}
[AppiumDriver@fe8b] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"appium:app":"/Users/dangood/Desktop/UIKitCatalog.app","appium:automationName":"XCUITest","appium:deviceName":"iPhone 12 Pro","appium:platformName":"iOS","appium:platformVersion":"14.4","appium:wdaLocalPort":"4723","appium:newCommandTimeout":3600,"appium:connectHardwareKeyboard":true},null,{"alwaysMatch":{"appium:app":"/Users/dangood/Desktop/UIKitCatalog.app","appium:automationName":"XCUITest","appium:deviceName":"iPhone 12 Pro","appium:platformName":"iOS","appium:platformVersion":"14.4","appium:wdaLocalPort":"4723","appium:newCommandTimeout":3600,"appium:connectHardwareKeyboard":true},"firstMatch":[{}]}]
[AppiumDriver@fe8b] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1723815619719 (14:40:19 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time))
[BaseDriver] The capabilities ["platformName"] are standard capabilities and do not require "appium:" prefix
[Appium] Attempting to find matching driver for automationName 'XCUITest' and platformName 'iOS'
[Appium] The 'xcuitest' driver was installed and matched caps.
[Appium] Will require it at /Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver
[Appium] Requiring driver at /Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/build/index.js
[AppiumDriver@fe8b] Appium v2.11.3 creating new XCUITestDriver (v7.24.15) session
[AppiumDriver@fe8b] Checking BaseDriver versions for Appium and XCUITestDriver
[AppiumDriver@fe8b] Appium's BaseDriver version is 9.11.3
[AppiumDriver@fe8b] XCUITestDriver's BaseDriver version is 9.11.3
[XCUITestDriver@dcba] 
[XCUITestDriver@dcba] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {
  "alwaysMatch": {
    "appium:app": "/Users/dangood/Desktop/UIKitCatalog.app",
    "appium:automationName": "XCUITest",
    "appium:deviceName": "iPhone 12 Pro",
    "platformName": "iOS",
    "appium:platformVersion": "14.4",
    "appium:wdaLocalPort": "4723",
    "appium:newCommandTimeout": 3600,
    "appium:connectHardwareKeyboard": true
  },
  "firstMatch": [
    {}
  ]
}
[BaseDriver] Number capability passed in as string. Functionality may be compromised.
[XCUITestDriver@dcba] Capability 'wdaLocalPort' changed from string ('4723') to integer (4723). This may cause unexpected behavior
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Session created with session id: a51ca069-c645-40ba-93ab-cc39aaea5607
[a51ca069][XCUITest] Current user: 'dangood'
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] No real device udid has been provided in capabilities. Will select a matching simulator to run the test.
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] iOS SDK Version set to '14.4'
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Looking for an existing Simulator with platformName: iOS, platformVersion: 14.4, deviceName: iPhone 12 Pro
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Constructing iOS simulator for Xcode version 12.4 with udid 'C6D32AE1-C4C3-4B27-AFB9-1F6DF6DC2240'
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Determining device to run tests on: udid: 'C6D32AE1-C4C3-4B27-AFB9-1F6DF6DC2240', real device: false
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Event 'xcodeDetailsRetrieved' logged at 1723815621363 (14:40:21 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time))
[a51ca069][BaseDriver] Using local app '/Users/dangood/Desktop/UIKitCatalog.app'
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Caching the manifest for com.example.apple-samplecode.UICatalog app from a file source using the key '17d104b9ca0089216e38fa73e770a584e461367a'
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Event 'appConfigured' logged at 1723815621458 (14:40:21 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time))
[a51ca069][XCUITest] Checking whether app '/Users/dangood/Desktop/UIKitCatalog.app' is actually present on file system
[a51ca069][XCUITest] App is present
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] CFBundleIdentifier: "com.example.apple-samplecode.UICatalog"
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Event 'resetStarted' logged at 1723815621522 (14:40:21 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time))
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Not scrubbing third party app in anticipation of uninstall
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Event 'resetComplete' logged at 1723815622112 (14:40:22 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time))
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Using WDA path: '/Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent'
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Using WDA agent: '/Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj'
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Starting log capture for iOS Simulator with udid 'C6D32AE1-C4C3-4B27-AFB9-1F6DF6DC2240' using simctl
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Event 'logCaptureStarted' logged at 1723815625676 (14:40:25 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time))
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Setting up simulator
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Setting preferences of C6D32AE1-C4C3-4B27-AFB9-1F6DF6DC2240 Simulator to {"ConnectHardwareKeyboard":true}
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Setting common Simulator preferences to {"RotateWindowWhenSignaledByGuest":true,"StartLastDeviceOnLaunch":false,"DetachOnWindowClose":false,"AttachBootedOnStart":true,"ConnectHardwareKeyboard":true,"PasteboardAutomaticSync":false}
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Updated C6D32AE1-C4C3-4B27-AFB9-1F6DF6DC2240 Simulator preferences at '/Users/dangood/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist' with {"RotateWindowWhenSignaledByGuest":true,"StartLastDeviceOnLaunch":false,"DetachOnWindowClose":false,"AttachBootedOnStart":true,"ConnectHardwareKeyboard":true,"PasteboardAutomaticSync":false,"DevicePreferences":{"C6D32AE1-C4C3-4B27-AFB9-1F6DF6DC2240":{"ConnectHardwareKeyboard":true,"SimulatorExternalDisplay":2114,"SimulatorWindowRotationAngle":0,"SimulatorWindowGeometry":{"D4A52076-1F28-4865-B221-D239FBBC2C68":{"WindowCenter":"{1042.5, 413}","WindowScale":0.7432735426008968}},"SimulatorWindowOrientation":"Portrait","ChromeTint":""}}}
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Got Simulator UI client PID: 30290
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Both Simulator with UDID 'C6D32AE1-C4C3-4B27-AFB9-1F6DF6DC2240' and the UI client are currently running
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Event 'simStarted' logged at 1723815628603 (14:40:28 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time))
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Verifying application platform
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] CFBundleSupportedPlatforms: ["iPhoneSimulator"]
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] CFBundleExecutable: "UIKitCatalog"
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] /Users/dangood/Desktop/UIKitCatalog.app/UIKitCatalog: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] App 'com.example.apple-samplecode.UICatalog' is already installed
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Reset requested. Removing app with id 'com.example.apple-samplecode.UICatalog' from the device
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Installing '/Users/dangood/Desktop/UIKitCatalog.app' on Simulator with UUID 'C6D32AE1-C4C3-4B27-AFB9-1F6DF6DC2240'...
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] The app has been successfully installed in 5267ms
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Event 'appInstalled' logged at 1723815646908 (14:40:46 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time))
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] No obsolete cached processes from previous WDA sessions listening on port 4723 have been found
[a51ca069][DevCon Factory] Requesting connection for device C6D32AE1-C4C3-4B27-AFB9-1F6DF6DC2240 on local port 4723
[a51ca069][DevCon Factory] Cached connections count: 0
[a51ca069][DevCon Factory] Successfully requested the connection for C6D32AE1-C4C3-4B27-AFB9-1F6DF6DC2240:4723
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Starting WebDriverAgent initialization with the synchronization key 'XCUITestDriver'
[a51ca069][WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[a51ca069][WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:4723/status] with no body
[HTTP] --> GET /status {}
[AppiumDriver@fe8b] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
[AppiumDriver@fe8b] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"ready":true,"message":"The server is ready to accept new connections","build":{"version":"2.11.3"}}
[HTTP] <-- GET /status 200 9 ms - 111 
[a51ca069][WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"ready":true,"message":"The server is ready to accept new connections","build":{"version":"2.11.3"}}}
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Upgrade timestamp of the currently bundled WDA: 1723648040907
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Upgrade timestamp of the WDA on the device: undefined
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Will reuse previously cached WDA instance at 'http://127.0.0.1:4723/'. Set the wdaLocalPort capability to a value different from 4723 if this is an undesired behavior.
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Trying to start WebDriverAgent 2 times with 10000ms interval
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] These values can be customized by changing wdaStartupRetries/wdaStartupRetryInterval capabilities
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Event 'wdaStartAttempted' logged at 1723815648206 (14:40:48 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time))
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Using provided WebdriverAgent at 'http://127.0.0.1:4723/'
[a51ca069][WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[a51ca069][WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:4723/status] with no body
[HTTP] --> GET /status {}
[AppiumDriver@fe8b] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
[AppiumDriver@fe8b] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"ready":true,"message":"The server is ready to accept new connections","build":{"version":"2.11.3"}}
[HTTP] <-- GET /status 200 9 ms - 111 
[a51ca069][WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"ready":true,"message":"The server is ready to accept new connections","build":{"version":"2.11.3"}}}
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Event 'wdaSessionAttempted' logged at 1723815648333 (14:40:48 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time))
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Sending createSession command to WDA
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Matched '/session' to command name 'createSession'
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:4723/session] with body: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"bundleId":"com.example.apple-samplecode.UICatalog","arguments":[],"environment":{},"eventloopIdleDelaySec":0,"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":false,"maxTypingFrequency":60,"shouldUseSingletonTestManager":true,"shouldTerminateApp":true,"forceAppLaunch":true,"useNativeCachingStrategy":true,"forceSimulatorSoftwareKeyboardPresence":false}],"alwaysMatch":{}}}
[HTTP] --> POST /session {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"bundleId":"com.example.apple-samplecode.UICatalog","arguments":[],"environment":{},"eventloopIdleDelaySec":0,"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":false,"maxTypingFrequency":60,"shouldUseSingletonTestManager":true,"shouldTerminateApp":true,"forceAppLaunch":true,"useNativeCachingStrategy":true,"forceSimulatorSoftwareKeyboardPresence":false}],"alwaysMatch":{}}}
[AppiumDriver@fe8b] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [null,null,{"firstMatch":[{"bundleId":"com.example.apple-samplecode.UICatalog","arguments":[],"environment":{},"eventloopIdleDelaySec":0,"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":false,"maxTypingFrequency":60,"shouldUseSingletonTestManager":true,"shouldTerminateApp":true,"forceAppLaunch":true,"useNativeCachingStrategy":true,"forceSimulatorSoftwareKeyboardPresence":false}],"alwaysMatch":{}}]
[AppiumDriver@fe8b] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1723815648414 (14:40:48 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time))
[Appium] Could not parse W3C capabilities: All non-standard capabilities should have a vendor prefix. The following capabilities did not have one: bundleId,arguments,environment,eventloopIdleDelaySec,shouldWaitForQuiescence,shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection,maxTypingFrequency,shouldUseSingletonTestManager,shouldTerminateApp,forceAppLaunch,useNativeCachingStrategy,forceSimulatorSoftwareKeyboardPresence
[AppiumDriver@fe8b] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1723815648422 (14:40:48 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time))
[AppiumDriver@fe8b] Encountered internal error running command: InvalidArgumentError: All non-standard capabilities should have a vendor prefix. The following capabilities did not have one: bundleId,arguments,environment,eventloopIdleDelaySec,shouldWaitForQuiescence,shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection,maxTypingFrequency,shouldUseSingletonTestManager,shouldTerminateApp,forceAppLaunch,useNativeCachingStrategy,forceSimulatorSoftwareKeyboardPresence
    at parseCaps (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/basedriver/capabilities.ts:253:11)
    at processCapabilities (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/basedriver/capabilities.ts:325:43)
    at parseCapsForInnerDriver (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/utils.js:152:40)
    at AppiumDriver.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:636:49)
    at runCommandPromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/basedriver/driver.ts:115:20)
    at AppiumDriver.executeCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/basedriver/driver.ts:149:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at defaultBehavior (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:1119:16)
    at AppiumDriver.executeWrappedCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:1229:16)
    at AppiumDriver.executeCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:1135:17)
    at asyncHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:387:19)
[HTTP] <-- POST /session 400 243 ms - 2017 
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Got response with status 400: {"value":{"error":"invalid argument","message":"All non-standard capabilities should have a vendor prefix. The following capabilities did not have one: bundleId,arguments,environment,eventloopIdleDelaySec,shouldWaitForQuiescence,shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection,maxTypingFrequency,shouldUseSingletonTestManager,shouldTerminateApp,forceAppLaunch,useNativeCachingStrategy,forceSimulatorSoftwareKeyboardPresence","stacktrace":"InvalidArgumentError: All non-standard capabilities should have a vendor prefix. The following capabilities did not have one: bundleId,arguments,environment,eventloopIdleDelaySec,shouldWaitForQuiescence,shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection,maxTypingFrequency,shouldUseSingletonTestManager,shouldTerminateApp,forceAppLaunch,useNativeCachingStrategy,forceSimulatorSoftwareKeyboardPresence\n    at parseCaps (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/basedriver/capabilities.ts:253:11)\n    at processCapabilities (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node...
[a51ca069][W3C] Matched W3C error code 'invalid argument' to InvalidArgumentError
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Event 'wdaSessionFailed' logged at 1723815649375 (14:40:49 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time))
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] InvalidArgumentError: All non-standard capabilities should have a vendor prefix. The following capabilities did not have one: bundleId,arguments,environment,eventloopIdleDelaySec,shouldWaitForQuiescence,shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection,maxTypingFrequency,shouldUseSingletonTestManager,shouldTerminateApp,forceAppLaunch,useNativeCachingStrategy,forceSimulatorSoftwareKeyboardPresence
    at errorFromW3CJsonCode (/Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:1112:25)
    at ProxyRequestError.getActualError (/Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:981:14)
    at JWProxy.command (/Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/jsonwp-proxy/proxy.js:353:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at XCUITestDriver.proxyCommand (/Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/commands/proxy-helper.js:103:35)
    at XCUITestDriver.startWdaSession (/Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:1308:5)
    at /Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:883:11
    at wrapped (/Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/asyncbox/lib/asyncbox.js:93:13)
    at retry (/Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/asyncbox/lib/asyncbox.js:66:13)
    at retryInterval (/Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/asyncbox/lib/asyncbox.js:103:10)
    at /Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:837:7
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Parsed BUILD_DIR configuration value: '/Users/dangood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-erdyffhdcodljbhknjyalevzygmt/Build/Products'
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Got derived data root: '/Users/dangood/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-erdyffhdcodljbhknjyalevzygmt'
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Event 'wdaStartAttempted' logged at 1723815659448 (14:40:59 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time))
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Using provided WebdriverAgent at 'http://127.0.0.1:4723/'
[a51ca069][WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[a51ca069][WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:4723/status] with no body
[HTTP] --> GET /status {}
[AppiumDriver@fe8b] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
[AppiumDriver@fe8b] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"ready":true,"message":"The server is ready to accept new connections","build":{"version":"2.11.3"}}
[HTTP] <-- GET /status 200 6 ms - 111 
[a51ca069][WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"ready":true,"message":"The server is ready to accept new connections","build":{"version":"2.11.3"}}}
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Event 'wdaSessionAttempted' logged at 1723815659636 (14:40:59 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time))
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Sending createSession command to WDA
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Matched '/session' to command name 'createSession'
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:4723/session] with body: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"bundleId":"com.example.apple-samplecode.UICatalog","arguments":[],"environment":{},"eventloopIdleDelaySec":0,"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":false,"maxTypingFrequency":60,"shouldUseSingletonTestManager":true,"shouldTerminateApp":true,"forceAppLaunch":true,"useNativeCachingStrategy":true,"forceSimulatorSoftwareKeyboardPresence":false}],"alwaysMatch":{}}}
[HTTP] --> POST /session {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"bundleId":"com.example.apple-samplecode.UICatalog","arguments":[],"environment":{},"eventloopIdleDelaySec":0,"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":false,"maxTypingFrequency":60,"shouldUseSingletonTestManager":true,"shouldTerminateApp":true,"forceAppLaunch":true,"useNativeCachingStrategy":true,"forceSimulatorSoftwareKeyboardPresence":false}],"alwaysMatch":{}}}
[AppiumDriver@fe8b] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [null,null,{"firstMatch":[{"bundleId":"com.example.apple-samplecode.UICatalog","arguments":[],"environment":{},"eventloopIdleDelaySec":0,"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":false,"maxTypingFrequency":60,"shouldUseSingletonTestManager":true,"shouldTerminateApp":true,"forceAppLaunch":true,"useNativeCachingStrategy":true,"forceSimulatorSoftwareKeyboardPresence":false}],"alwaysMatch":{}}]
[AppiumDriver@fe8b] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1723815662230 (14:41:02 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time))
[Appium] Could not parse W3C capabilities: All non-standard capabilities should have a vendor prefix. The following capabilities did not have one: bundleId,arguments,environment,eventloopIdleDelaySec,shouldWaitForQuiescence,shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection,maxTypingFrequency,shouldUseSingletonTestManager,shouldTerminateApp,forceAppLaunch,useNativeCachingStrategy,forceSimulatorSoftwareKeyboardPresence
[AppiumDriver@fe8b] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1723815662239 (14:41:02 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time))
[AppiumDriver@fe8b] Encountered internal error running command: InvalidArgumentError: All non-standard capabilities should have a vendor prefix. The following capabilities did not have one: bundleId,arguments,environment,eventloopIdleDelaySec,shouldWaitForQuiescence,shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection,maxTypingFrequency,shouldUseSingletonTestManager,shouldTerminateApp,forceAppLaunch,useNativeCachingStrategy,forceSimulatorSoftwareKeyboardPresence
    at parseCaps (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/basedriver/capabilities.ts:253:11)
    at processCapabilities (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/basedriver/capabilities.ts:325:43)
    at parseCapsForInnerDriver (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/utils.js:152:40)
    at AppiumDriver.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:636:49)
    at runCommandPromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/basedriver/driver.ts:115:20)
    at AppiumDriver.executeCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/basedriver/driver.ts:149:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at defaultBehavior (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:1119:16)
    at AppiumDriver.executeWrappedCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:1229:16)
    at AppiumDriver.executeCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:1135:17)
    at asyncHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:387:19)
[HTTP] <-- POST /session 400 1791 ms - 2017 
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Got response with status 400: {"value":{"error":"invalid argument","message":"All non-standard capabilities should have a vendor prefix. The following capabilities did not have one: bundleId,arguments,environment,eventloopIdleDelaySec,shouldWaitForQuiescence,shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection,maxTypingFrequency,shouldUseSingletonTestManager,shouldTerminateApp,forceAppLaunch,useNativeCachingStrategy,forceSimulatorSoftwareKeyboardPresence","stacktrace":"InvalidArgumentError: All non-standard capabilities should have a vendor prefix. The following capabilities did not have one: bundleId,arguments,environment,eventloopIdleDelaySec,shouldWaitForQuiescence,shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection,maxTypingFrequency,shouldUseSingletonTestManager,shouldTerminateApp,forceAppLaunch,useNativeCachingStrategy,forceSimulatorSoftwareKeyboardPresence\n    at parseCaps (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/basedriver/capabilities.ts:253:11)\n    at processCapabilities (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node...
[a51ca069][W3C] Matched W3C error code 'invalid argument' to InvalidArgumentError
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Event 'wdaSessionFailed' logged at 1723815662385 (14:41:02 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time))
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] InvalidArgumentError: All non-standard capabilities should have a vendor prefix. The following capabilities did not have one: bundleId,arguments,environment,eventloopIdleDelaySec,shouldWaitForQuiescence,shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection,maxTypingFrequency,shouldUseSingletonTestManager,shouldTerminateApp,forceAppLaunch,useNativeCachingStrategy,forceSimulatorSoftwareKeyboardPresence
    at errorFromW3CJsonCode (/Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:1112:25)
    at ProxyRequestError.getActualError (/Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:981:14)
    at JWProxy.command (/Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/jsonwp-proxy/proxy.js:353:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at XCUITestDriver.proxyCommand (/Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/commands/proxy-helper.js:103:35)
    at XCUITestDriver.startWdaSession (/Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:1308:5)
    at /Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:883:11
    at wrapped (/Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/asyncbox/lib/asyncbox.js:93:13)
    at retry (/Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/asyncbox/lib/asyncbox.js:66:13)
    at retryInterval (/Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/asyncbox/lib/asyncbox.js:103:10)
    at /Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:837:7
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] {}
[a51ca069][DevCon Factory] Releasing connections for C6D32AE1-C4C3-4B27-AFB9-1F6DF6DC2240 device on any port number
[a51ca069][DevCon Factory] Found cached connections to release: ["C6D32AE1-C4C3-4B27-AFB9-1F6DF6DC2240:4723"]
[a51ca069][DevCon Factory] Cached connections count: 0
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Not clearing log files. Use `clearSystemFiles` capability to turn on.
[a51ca069][XCUITestDriver@dcba] Stopping iOS log capture
[a51ca069][AppiumDriver@fe8b] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1723815665449 (14:41:05 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time))
[a51ca069][AppiumDriver@fe8b] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unable to start WebDriverAgent session. Original error: All non-standard capabilities should have a vendor prefix. The following capabilities did not have one: bundleId,arguments,environment,eventloopIdleDelaySec,shouldWaitForQuiescence,shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection,maxTypingFrequency,shouldUseSingletonTestManager,shouldTerminateApp,forceAppLaunch,useNativeCachingStrategy,forceSimulatorSoftwareKeyboardPresence
    at /Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:897:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at wrapped (/Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/asyncbox/lib/asyncbox.js:93:13)
    at retry (/Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/asyncbox/lib/asyncbox.js:66:13)
    at retryInterval (/Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/asyncbox/lib/asyncbox.js:103:10)
    at /Users/dangood/.appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:837:7
[a51ca069][HTTP] <-- POST /session 500 48237 ms - 1352

I've tried adding all the additional capabilities that are complained about in the server log to the Appium Inspector in order to over-ride them so that the attributes had the necessary "appium" pre-fix but to no avail.
I've tried using a different port, not specifying a port, uninstalling appium and reinstalling appium, clearing the simulator cache but no joy as yet...
